# Dictionary with search by endings

Tags: ressources, genre, dictionnaires, suffixes

Is there a French dictionary where I can search for words with given ending? It would also be nice to have the results sorted by frequence and the nouns marked with gender.

I want to check some popular recommendations about gender of French nouns, like *nouns ending on -age (-ade) are generally masculine (feminine)*. If you know some researches on this theme, they are also welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Lexique.org](http://www.lexique.org/outils/Manuel_Lexique.htm#_Toc152122362) provides an advanced search tool.

Searching for words ending with -age or -ade is done from [that page](http://www.lexique.org/moteur/Open.php?base%5B0%5D=lexique3&nbfields=4&Open_Lexique=Recherche) that way:

[image: image 1]

and leads to [this result](http://www.lexique.org/moteur/complexe.php?regex=1&nom_champs%5B1%5D=lexique3.ortho&like%5B1%5D=&champs%5B1%5D=.*a%5Bdg%5De%24&nom_champs%5B2%5D=lexique3.ortho&like%5B2%5D=&champs%5B2%5D=&nom_champs%5B3%5D=lexique3.ortho&like%5B3%5D=&champs%5B3%5D=&nom_champs%5B4%5D=lexique3.ortho&like%5B4%5D=&champs%5B4%5D=&tri=lexique3.ortho&sens=ASC&pers%5B0%5D=*&pers%5B0%5D=lexique3.ortho&pers%5B1%5D=lexique3.genre&pers%5B2%5D=lexique3.phon&pers%5B3%5D=lexique3.freqlivres&pers%5B4%5D=Non_Sp%E9cifi%E9&pers%5B5%5D=Non_Sp%E9cifi%E9&database=lexique.lexique3&lienbdd=&Rechercher=Rechercher&nblignes=2000&format=html).

[image: image2]

...

Answer (score 0):

#### Le Wiktionnaire

[Le Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org) allows for this kind of search. It may not be complete (especially, it does not always have a list of names composed with this ending) but it usually features at least some examples and it does say whether that ending is masculine or feminine.

For your examples:

- -age: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/-age (masculine, missing a list of composites)
- -ade: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ade (feminine)

#### Le Centre National de Ressources Textuelles et Lexicales

The [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/) also proposes this kind of definitions, with seemingly more complete lists of names made from the suffixes. I am less familiar with it, but some others on this StackExchange will have much more knowledge about it.

Same examples:

- -age: http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-age
- -ade: http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-ade

Answer (score 0):

In book form, you can use the Dictionnaire des rimes edited by Larousse.